# run php script in the background - windows

Tags: php, windows, background

I want to run php script that runs an infinity loop in the background of another php page without stopping or affecting the caller page, 
what I've tried so far is this:
in the caller page:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true); 
$path=realpath('./infinity.php');
$cmd='c:/xampp/php/php'.$path;
if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
   exec("start/b C:\\xampp\\php\\php $path > NUL");
} 
else { 
    exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
}
```

in infinity.php

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

my problem is that when I try to open the caller page in the browser i see the loading mark forever and the page is never open!

could you tell me what I'm missing?
notice: 
- i'm working on windows 8 
- i've used set_time_limit(0) and ignore_user_abort(true) in both pages since i don't know how exactly i suppose  to use them.

i know my question might be duplicated but i've tried all of the proposed solutions and i still can't open the caller page

any help is appreciated

Comment: PHP is not asynchronous or multithreaded. Your infinite loop will block any other process until it exits. You could look at other technologies more appropriate to this problem, or clarify why you need to do this (we might be able to suggest a better PHP option).

Answer (score -2):

This has worked for me but note that this is on a Linux box!

```
$cmd = "/path/to/script/to/run/in/background.php $var1 $var2";
$outputfile = '/path/to/script/output.txt';
$pidfile = '/path/to/process/id/file.txt';
$exe = exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
```

This will run background.php in a shell outside of your first script. The first script will carry on running as normal and not wait for background.php to finish. Because the script will be running in the background it is important to get and store the PID somewhere so you can check on the script from time to time. i.e. Is it still running. outputfile and pidfile need to be writeable by the script.

Sorry I started writing this response before I realised you were working in a windows environment! Maybe still of some use though. (maybe not..)

Comment: people who know that this is possible in linux and not in windows only comes to your answer dude.